# VLOOKUP multiple values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2010

I hope someone can help with this, I'm trying to find the wage in the tables and return what the percentage would be based on filing status.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done without the volatile Offset, using Index/Match. The challenge here is that you first have to locate the column in which to perform the match. This column can be found with and Index on the wage columns, using an exact match to find the filing status in row 2. Note that the second argument for the rows remains blank. Index will then return a range, not a single cell.

```
INDEX($C$3:$D$12,,MATCH($H$3,$C$2:$D$2,0))
```

In that range you want to match the wage with an approximate lookup, using a 1 as the last argument, which requires the data to be sorted.

```
MATCH($H$2,INDEX($C$3:$D$12,,MATCH($H$3,$C$2:$D$2,0)),1)
```

This returns the row number of the found or approximate match. Use that row number inside another Index on the tax rate. Here is the complete formula

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$12,MATCH($H$2,INDEX($C$3:$D$12,,MATCH($H$3,$C$2:$D$2,0)),1))
```

[image]

Comment: So I updated my chosen answer because this one worked on another application that I'm also working on, but with some problems. Is it possible to use this to lookup values in multiple tables with multiple conditions?

Comment: If you feel the need to perform a lookup into multiple tables with multiple conditions, it may be time to re-organize your data architecture. Keep things simple. Consolidate the multiple tables into one. But that is a new question, really.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the plain `LOOKUP` function in Excel. It is important the table is sorted. Armed with that value you can then perform the VLOOKUP, just like in your formula.

I would use `OFFSET` and `MATCH` to shift the lookup range according to status. For example your formula could look like this:

`=LOOKUP(H1,OFFSET(C3:C9,0,MATCH(H2,C2:E2,0)-1),B3:B9)`

You can find more info on this here: https://exceljet.net/formula/lookup-value-between-two-numbers

Comment: Can you elaborate, please

Comment: As far as I can tell you want to lookup a value, even though it is not explicitly contained in the table is that correct?

Comment: yes that correct

Comment: Updated the answer. You cannot lookup inside the range directly. LOOKUP will return either that range or another one you specify.

Comment: You make now sense

Comment: Added demo formula. Should work. Note the cheeky -1 in there to make offset and match work together. Hope that has now answered your question!

Comment: Thanks answered one question

Comment: Offset is volatile and should be avoided. This is a case for Index/Match

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to step away from `VLOOKUP()` if you don't wish to.

The problem you are having is **NOT** due to `VLOOKUP()` being able to do the desired lookups. The problem is that you are doing the wrong lookup.

Your formula looks up the value in H2, but in the tables B2:E9 and B11:E20. `VLOOKUP()` uses the first column in the table for the lookup. Well, the first column in the table you give it to look in is column B which has percentages. Percentages in this case that are all <1. So you seek $540 in a column that has no value >1... it must reach the last value, find no higher value, and settle on that highest value found. Then it looks over into the other three columns for the proper amount to return.

Well, you can't expect that to work... Anyone earning over 37¢ in the period will always see the last row selected.

You could use:

```
=VLOOKUP(G2,INDEX(A1:D8,ROW(1:8),IFS(G3="Single",{2,1},G3="Married",{3,1},G3="HoH",{4,1},TRUE,"")),2,TRUE)
```

You have four parameters to `VLOOKUP()`. The first one is easy, it's the income amount for the period, G2. The last one is easy too, it's the TRUE value so that the lookup does not look for an exact match.

The interesting parameter is the second one, the table for the lookup to use. Because you will use `INDEX()` to select the columns to use and to rearrange them, the third parameter is easy too, it is "2" for the second column of the lookup table you use.

A two column lookup table??? There are four columns? Not two? What gives?

`INDEX()` lets you give it a range and then select from it one or more rows and one or more columns. In fact, that's what `INDEX/MATCH` is all about, though one is usually looking for a single value in that case. So you will use `INDEX()` to select only two columns from the four columns, the first will be the lookup column (this is how `VLOOKUP()` works) and so the second column will be the results column, the tax rates.

When you select either columns or rows in this manner, you must use an expression for the other that demands definite rows (one or all, but directly specified) so you cannot do the "leave that value blank" or "use a zero to get all rows/columns" techniques. In this case you want all the rows in the original table, eight of them, so use one of the usual methods:

1. `ROW(1:8)`
2. `SEQUENCE(8)`  (not available in 2019, I believe)

So then the only magic left is how to specify the columns. You could just type an `array constant` like `{2,39,23,24,25,2,2,8,1,33}` if you had a simple situation, but you have a situation in which you need one of three possible array constants:

1. {2,1} if Single
2. {3,1} if Married
3. {4,1} if HoH

The `IFS()` is any easy way to get that since there are so few. More? At some point, you'd prefer a table and a lookup of its own. Have to change them often? Definitely prefer a table and its own lookup inside the formula. In any case, it's simple here so I used an `IFS()` that is very simple (but more than half the length of the formula!).

Still, one last thing might look strange... why do all those array constants end in 1? Well, that's because the original table (the one you show in your question) has the values you need looked up in ITS column 1 and you have to have them in column 2 for your actual lookup table, the one `INDEX()` is creating on the fly. So they all have the tax rates column come 2nd so `VLOOKUP()` will work.

This method is meant to be instructive so you can get a lot more mileage out of `INDEX()` with that reordering technique. It works with other things too:  `FILTER()` being a BIG use, but even `VLOOKUP()` can take one array constant like that. In that case, it might be for the results column. By specifying several in an array constant instead of a single one like the plain 2 in this formula, you can get several results in one go. Want to look up one thing, once, and get results from five of the lookup table's columns? Use an array constant instead of a single column number. No need for five separate lookups. And there are other functions that can use it too.

Obviously, "in the day," the simple `INDEX/MATCH` in the accepted answer was the quickest, easiest way. Now one supposes `XLOOKUP()` would be, and maybe that was available then. In neither then nor now would one prefer the above formula.

I answered with it partly as a `VLOOKUP()` fan (HATE hearing the absolutely wrong "it won't 'look left'", for example:  it does so three ways in this formula!), but mostly to show one of the many ways one can do some things and emphasize one of the great aspects of `INDEX()` and the fact that it can be handy in some other often used functions.